# Pandas or Numpy: how to get matching data entries to do data manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Say, for example, that I have two data relations like this:

```
Data1:
   C1      C2
"Peter"  "kiwi"
"John"   "banana"
"Susan"  "peach"
"Joe"    "apple"

Data2:
   C3      C4
"apple"     4 
"banana"    7
"apple"     4
```

For each row in data1, I would like to find all the possible matches on the common attribute (say between Data1[C2] and Data2[C3]) and sum the Data2[C4] values for all matches found.

More concretely to the example, I want the resulting computation to be like:

```
"Peter":  0 (no match for "kiwi")
"John":   7 (one match for "banana", it's just 7)
"Susan":  0 (no match for "peach")
"Joe":    8 (two matches for "apple", they're 4+4)
```

How can I accomplish this using the pandas dataframe, or numpy, efficiently?

Thank you so much for help. I'll edit the question title to be more relevant after I get more input on the technical details involved with this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### One way is to user `merge` and `groupby`:

```
data1.merge(data2, left_on='C2', right_on='C3', how='left')[['C1', 'C4']]\
     .fillna(0)\
     .groupby('C1')\
     .sum()
```

Output:

```
        C1   C4
0    "Joe"  8.0
1   "John"  7.0
2  "Peter"  0.0
3  "Susan"  0.0
```

To get dictionary ouput:

```
data1.merge(data2, left_on='C2', right_on='C3', how='left')[['C1', 'C4']]\
     .fillna(0)\
     .groupby('C1')\
     .sum()\
     .T\
     .to_dict('r')
```

Output:

```
[{'"Joe"': 8.0, '"John"': 7.0, '"Peter"': 0.0, '"Susan"': 0.0}]
```

#### Another way is to use `map` with `sum`:

```
data1['Score'] = data1['C2'].map(data2.set_index('C3', append=True)\
                            .sum(level=1)['C4']).fillna(0)
data1[['C1', 'Score']]
```

Output:

```
        C1  Score
0  "Peter"    0.0
1   "John"    7.0
2  "Susan"    0.0
3    "Joe"    8.0
```

#### Add-on for comment:

```
data1.merge(data2.rename_axis('d2_idx').reset_index(), left_on='C2', right_on='C3', how='left')\
     .groupby('C1')['d2_idx','C4']\
     .agg({'d2_idx':lambda x: ', '.join(x.astype(str)), 'C4':'sum'})
```

Output:

```
           d2_idx   C4
C1                    
"Joe"    0.0, 2.0  8.0
"John"        1.0  7.0
"Peter"       nan  0.0
"Susan"       nan  0.0
```

Comment: @masteryiiintraining Did this solution help you?

Comment: Hey yes, absolutely - thank you so much! I'm new to Stack Overflow so forgot to hit the checkmark despite up-voting. I do have a follow-up question: is there some way that while computing the aggregated sum above I can also construct a dictionary of the values in data1[C4] mapped to the list of indices that matched from data2? I think I know how to do these two tasks separately, but wondering if there's an efficient way to make use of shared computations in between.

Comment: @MasterYiiinTraining Like this? See Add-on in the above solution.  Thank you.

Comment: So the step to compute the matching indices is excluded from my run-time evaluations, but the step to compute the sum needs to be included into my run-time evaluations. While the above add-on perform both tasks efficiently at once, is there some approach to compute the summation task from precomputed matching indices (to decrease the time of computing the sum)?

Comment: Hrm...  Good question.   Let me look at this a bit more.  If I come up with anything I'll update.  But, maybe you could get a better answer post a new follow up question to this one with that in mind.