# Pandas: How to keep track of the indices for the matching data entries between two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm still new to Pandas.

I'm trying to **cache the indices of matching data entries** between two Pandas data frames **in** the form of a **python dictionary** for more time efficient computations and hash lookups later on.

For example, I have two data frame relations.

```
R1:                     R2:

A        B              B        C
1        2              2        18
2        2              5        18
3        6              6        26
4        7              6        31
                        7        32
```

Column B is the common attribute between R1 and R2. I would like to construct a dictionary that maps each of the value in R1 to the indices of the matching data entries in R2.

e.g. desired output

```
{2: [0],        (2 from R1[B] matches with the 0th entry in R2)
 6: [2,3]       (6 from R1[B] matches with the 2nd and 3rd entry in R2)
 7: [4]}        (7 from R1[B] matches with the 4th entry in R2)
```

Is there an efficient way to that? It doesn't matter whether values in R1[B] that have no match in R2 show up as an item with empty list as value in the output dictionary, or is skipped altogether.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `reset_index` and `groupby` with R2 columns B , to get the `list` of `index` , then chain with `.loc`

```
R2.reset_index().groupby('B')['index'].apply(list).loc[R1.B.unique()]# if you need dict , adding to_dict() at the end 
B
2       [0]
6    [2, 3]
7       [4]
Name: index, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hey great solution, thanks! I have a follow-up question: is there some way to also take advantage of this series of indices to efficiently compute the sum of the values in R2['C'] for those matching indices? Like I'm trying to use the grouped indices to do computation as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53789284/pandas-or-numpy-how-to-get-matching-data-entries-to-do-data-manipulation (trying to perform both tasks and make use of the common intermediate computational info to speed up time).